# Rational function approximation to square root

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, approximation, elementary-functions

*I've already received a lot of help with this problem (thank you all), and I've written up an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2008838/284973) with all of the information I've got in it as to why these approximations are so good.*

My question is why the following [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) is such a good approximation for the square root of $x$?

$$\sqrt{x}\approx\frac{256+1792x+1120 x^{2}+112 x^{3}+x^{4}}{1024+1792x+448 x^{2}+16 x^{3}}$$

The following image illustrates that for $3\leqslant x\leqslant 7$ the two curves are almost identical:

[image]

More generally why does the following formula hold with such accuracy?:

$$\sqrt{n}\approx\frac{m^{8}+28 m^{6}n+70 m^{4}n^{2}+28 m^{2}n^{3}+n^{4}}{8 m^{7}+56 m^{5}n+56m^{3}n^{2}+8m n^{3}}$$

for any real number (*not* just integer) $n\geqslant 1$ and:

$$m=\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}\right\rfloor$$

The following graph shows that for $0\leqslant n\leqslant10000$ the two curves cannot be separated by eye:

[image]

And this is the logarithm of the error in that approximation which decreases cyclically (presumably due to the [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) in the definition of $m$) but then starts to become slightly less accurate stepwise as $n$ increases:

[image]

(**Edit**: Several people have mentioned [Pade approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) below and that the first formula is a Pade approximant, which explains why it is such a good approximation. I would really especially like to know why the second formula is such a good approximation on the wide range I have shown in the second graph (is it related to Pade approximants also?), and I would really love to know why the process I outline in the section below of how I got these functions gives Pade approximants at all from ratios of [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). At first glance, it seems as if there might be something deep going on here?)

---

### How I found these and what I already know:

While messing around with maths once I noticed that $(3+\sqrt{8})^{8}\approx1331714$ with very good accuracy. Since the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) gives that $(3+\sqrt{8})^{8}=665857+235416\sqrt{8}$ and since $1331714=2\times665857$ I saw that that gave the approximation:

$$\sqrt{8}\approx\frac{665857}{235416}$$

which is quite accurate. I found this intriguing, but exploring further I found that similar near integer results were produced by:

$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{8}\approx1154$$

$$(2+\sqrt{3})^{8}\approx37634$$

$$(2+\sqrt{4})^{8}=65536$$

$$(2+\sqrt{5})^{8}\approx103682$$

$$(2+\sqrt{6})^{8}\approx153632$$

$$(3+\sqrt{7})^{8}\approx1032224$$

and so on, and I found that in general I could get a very accurate near integer from any (at least small) expression of the form $(m+\sqrt{n})^{8}$ where as $n$ increased over the integers $m$ increased as:

$$m=\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}\right\rfloor$$

When these expressions were expanded out they were all in the form $a+b\sqrt{n}\approx2a$ where:

$$a=m^{8}+28 m^{6}n+70 m^{4}n^{2}+28 m^{2}n^{3}+n^{4}$$

$$b=8 m^{7}+56 m^{5}n+56m^{3}n^{2}+8m n^{3}$$

From this you get my original equations that I posted.

Now there is nothing particularly interesting about the eighth powers I have been working with; ninth powers work as well (slightly more accurately) and seventh powers are slightly less accurate, giving a similar formula:

$$\sqrt{n}\approx\frac{m^{7}+21 m^{5}n+35 m^{3} n^{2}+7m n^{3}}{7 m^{6}n+35 m^{4} n^{2}+21 m^{2} n^{3}+n^{4}}$$

Thus some of the reason behind these formulae must be the fact that the $m+\sqrt{n}$ have powers tending to integers, and just about the only thing I have been able to find out about why this might work is that some of these numbers are [Pisot-Vijayaraghavan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number) (i.e. their powers tend towards integers).

However, this does not explain the phenomenon, since I do not know why the effect would be greatest for $m=\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}\right\rfloor$ or importantly why the convergence should be of the form $(m+\sqrt{n})^{c}=a+b\sqrt{n}\approx 2a$ (which is where the approximation comes from) or why the formula derived should also hold for non-integral $n$. Rather the important part seems to lie in the formulation as:

$$\left(\frac{Even Binomial Terms}{Odd Binomial Terms}\right)^{\pm 1}$$

and perhaps in the expression $m=\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}\right\rfloor$.

So my question is: why do these formulae work?

Comment: I didn't look at your specific polynomials, but you could look into "Padé approximants" to see if there is any relation.

Comment: I have heard of Pade approximants, but I guess even if the functions I have mentioned are Pade approximants (i.e. most accurate for the given order of polynomials), that doesn't really answer my question since it doesn't explain why this method should give a Pade approximant in the first place. What I was really looking for was *why* my formula was a good approximation.

Comment: Fascinating, but possibly boiling down to a taylor-expansion of $\sqrt{x}$ in the range $[-1,1]$. If your formula actually is a Pade-approximation, this could be an explanation. First of all, we need to understand how $m$ depends on $n$ to get an idea what exactly is going on. I will work on it.

Comment: If $m^2=n$, then the result is $m$, which is exact! So, we have to find out, how $\frac{a}{b}$ depends on $\frac{m^2}{n}$, which will be always near $1$ if $n$ is large.

Comment: @Peter, that does seem like a useful way to approach this. I'd love to know if you find anything; this has intrigued me ever since I found it!

Comment: @Anon Unfortunately, I have no access to Wolfram alpha (the server might be down). I begun with an answer, but I deleted it since it is incomplete. But if I find a result, I can undelete it. Anyway, a very powerful formula, only needing integers!

Comment: What might help : $m$ is just $\sqrt{n}$, correctly rounded to the next natural number.

Comment: @Peter Ah... I think I see what you're getting at. If you plug $m\approx\sqrt{n}$ into the formula then what comes out is $\frac{128 n^{4}}{128 n^{3.5}}$. That's awesome, if you could end up writing that up into an answer, and explain why my formula for $m$ is $\sqrt{n}$ rounded to the nearest integer, then I'll definitely accept your answer. If you might be able to give an intuitive explanation of just *why* the ratio of binomial terms that comes out of the near integer approximations gives a Pade approximant, then that would be even more awesome!

Comment: The perfect answer to this question would include a mention of what Barry has identified in his answer, as well as some explanation of the appearance of the Pade approximant.

Comment: @Anon Yesterday, I had big problems with the internet, today it seems to work fine and even Wolfram Alpha is available again. It is nice that you would accept an answer containing an information why $m$ is $\sqrt{n}$, correctly rounded, but this would not explain the astonishing accuracy. That $m=\sqrt{n}$ plugged in, gives $\sqrt{n}$ is clear because I already mentioned that plugging $m^2=n$ gives $m$. But $\sqrt{n}$ is a bit larger or smaller. In short, the observation $m=round(\sqrt{n})$ will be helpful, but not at all sufficient to "cut the knot".

Comment: @Anon I have not found a Pade-approximation yet coinciding with your fraction, but maybe your fraction is very near to a Pade-approximation, I have no idea yet.

Comment: @Peter Barry’s answer combined with your observation that $m=round(\sqrt{n})$ explains why $a/b$ is such a good approximation since from $(m+\sqrt{n})^{c}$ we derive $\sqrt{n}=\frac{a-(m-\sqrt{n})^{c}}{b}$ so for any $n$ (with accuracy improving as $c$ increases) $a/b$ will only differ from $\sqrt{n}$ by $\frac{(round(\sqrt{n})-\sqrt{n})^{c}}{b}$ which is going to be very small.

Comment: So I feel that explains why $\sqrt{n}\approx\frac{m^{8}+28 m^{6}n+70 m^{4}n^{2}+28 m^{2}n^{3}+n^{4}}{8 m^{7}+56 m^{5}n+56m^{3}n^{2}+8m n^{3}}$ is such a good approximation. The only interesting thing I can see left to find out is why (if Claude is correct) the result gives us a Pade approximant.

Comment: The error in the approximation thus seems like it should be $\frac{(round(\sqrt{n})-\sqrt{n})^{c}}{b}$ which will always be less than $\frac{1}{2^{c}b}$. I think that explains the accuracy, although I may have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Actually I don't think it is $round(\sqrt{n})$, which would be $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$ or something like that. The error's not much worse though.

Comment: I've now written up my own answer to this question incorporating the insights of everyone who's helped me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the many good answers and comments to this question, especially those of Peter and [Barry Cipra](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1986850/284973), I think I’ve come to understand the answers to most of my questions. Since none of the answers by other users here has all of the information in one place, and someone else might want to see in one place what helped me at least, I thought I’d write it all up into one answer (I've accepted the answer to make it obvious, I hope that's not considered rude). The main thing I'm answering is my question about why powers of $(m+\sqrt{n})$ give good approximations of $\sqrt{n}$, and also finding the error of the approximation.

When $(m+\sqrt{n})^c$ is expanded [binomially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) for $m,c\in\mathbb{N}$ and real $n>0$, we get:

$$(m+\sqrt{n})^c=\sum_{k=0}^{c}\binom{c}{k}m^k n^{\frac{c-k}{2}}$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{c}{2k}m^{2k}n^{\frac{c-2k}{2}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{c}{2}\right\rceil}\binom{c}{2k-1}m^{2k-1}n^{\frac{c-2k+1}{2}}$$

Now if $c$ is even then a factor of $\sqrt{n}$ can be taken out of the second sum as follows:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{c}{2k}m^{2k}n^{\frac{c-2k}{2}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{c}{2}\right\rceil}\binom{c}{2k-1}m^{2k-1}n^{\frac{c-2k+1}{2}}\\=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{c}{2k}m^{2k}n^{\frac{c-2k}{2}}+\sqrt{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{c}{2}\right\rceil}\binom{c}{2k-1}m^{2k-1}n^{\frac{c-2k}{2}}$$

such that the powers of $n$ in each sum are all integers, and if $c$ is odd then the same factor can be taken out of the first sum so that all powers of $n$ in the sums are integers:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{c}{2k}m^{2k}n^{\frac{c-2k}{2}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{c}{2}\right\rceil}\binom{c}{2k-1}m^{2k-1}n^{\frac{c-2k+1}{2}}\\=\sqrt{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{c}{2k}m^{2k}n^{\frac{c-2k-1}{2}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{c}{2}\right\rceil}\binom{c}{2k-1}m^{2k-1}n^{\frac{c-2k+1}{2}}$$

This gives us the following:

> $$(m+\sqrt{n})^c=a_{m,c}(n)+b_{m,c}(n)\sqrt{n}\tag{1}$$
>
> Where $a_{m,c}$ and $b_{m,c}$ are [polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) in $n$ given by:
>
> $$a_{m,c}(n)=\begin{cases}\sum_\limits{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{c}{2k}m^{2k}n^{\frac{c-2k}{2}}&c\text{ even}\\\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{c}{2}\right\rceil}\binom{c}{2k-1}m^{2k-1}n^{\frac{c-2k+1}{2}}&c\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$
>
> $$b_{m,c}(n)=\begin{cases}\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{c}{2}\right\rceil}\binom{c}{2k-1}m^{2k-1}n^{\frac{c-2k}{2}}&c\text{ even}\\\sum_\limits{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{c}{2k}m^{2k}n^{\frac{c-2k-1}{2}}&c\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$

(Note that these polynomials are the polynomials found in the rational approximation in the question). Now an analogous argument will show that:

$$(m-\sqrt{n})^c=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{c}{2k}(-1)^{\frac{c-2k}{2}}m^{2k}n^{\frac{c-2k}{2}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{c}{2}\right\rceil}\binom{c}{2k-1}(-1)^{\frac{c-2k+1}{2}}m^{2k-1}n^{\frac{c-2k+1}{2}}$$

And if $c$ is even then we have:

$$(m-\sqrt{n})^c=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{c}{2k}m^{2k}n^{\frac{c-2k}{2}}-\sqrt{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{c}{2}\right\rceil}\binom{c}{2k-1}m^{2k-1}n^{\frac{c-2k}{2}}$$

And if $c$ is odd then we have:

$$(m-\sqrt{n})^c=-\sqrt{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{c}{2k}m^{2k}n^{\frac{c-2k-1}{2}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{c}{2}\right\rceil}\binom{c}{2k-1}m^{2k-1}n^{\frac{c-2k+1}{2}}$$

So that we must have:

> $$(m-\sqrt{n})^c=a_{m,c}(n)-b_{m,c}(n)\sqrt{n}\tag{2}$$

Thus we can add $(1)$ and $(2)$ together to obtain:
$$(m+\sqrt{n})^c+(m-\sqrt{n})^c=2 a_{m,c}(n)$$

$$\therefore 2 a_{m,c}(n)=a_{m,c}(n)+b_{m,c}(n)\sqrt{n}+(m-\sqrt{n})^c$$

$$\therefore b_{m,c}(n)\sqrt{n}=a_{m,c}(n)-(m-\sqrt{n})^c$$

$$\therefore \sqrt{n}=\frac{a_{m,c}(n)-(m-\sqrt{n})^c}{b_{m,c}(n)}$$

Thus we have proved that the following approximation:

> $$\sqrt{n}\approx\frac{a_{m,c}(n)}{b_{m,c}(n)}$$

(which is exactly the form of the approximations in the question) will for any positive real number $n$ have an error $E$ of precisely:

> $$E=\frac{|m-\sqrt{n}|^c}{b_{m,c}(n)}$$

since $b_{m,c}$ is positive. If $m$ is constrained to be an integer near $\sqrt{n}$ then it is easy to see that this will be small, especially for large $c$ (for which $b_{m,c}$ will also increase).

Now a quick check shows that the formula for $m$ in the question never differs from $\sqrt{n}$ by more than around $0.75$ for $n>1$ so the error for $c=8$ will be always less then around $\frac{1}{10 b_{m,c}(n)}$ which will grow as $b_{m,c}$ grows (indeed as $n$ increases the bound on the error appears to decrease towards $\frac{1}{256 b_{m,c}(n)}$ although I haven't proved this). This explains why the following formula for instance:

$$\sqrt{n}\approx\frac{m^{8}+28 m^{6}n+70 m^{4}n^{2}+28 m^{2}n^{3}+n^{4}}{8 m^{7}+56 m^{5}n+56m^{3}n^{2}+8m n^{3}}$$

$$m=\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}\right\rfloor$$

is such a good approximation.

Indeed if we constrain $m$ to be an integer then the closest to $\sqrt{n}$ we could choose is $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$ in which case the error of the approximation would be always less than $\frac{1}{2^{c}b_{m,c}(n)}$ which will be very small. This appears to explain the accuracy of the formulae shown.

Answer (score 10):

Concerning the first question $$\sqrt{x}\approx\frac{x^4+112 x^3+1120 x^2+1792 x+256}{16 x^3+448 x^2+1792 x+1024}$$ is the $\text{Pade}_{(4,3)}$ expansion of $\sqrt x$ centered at $x=4$ (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant)).

Around a given point, any function can be approximated using Padé approximants which are ratios of polynomial of selected degrees.

If you consider $\text{Pade}_{(4,4)}$, it would be $$\sqrt{x}\approx \frac{9 x^4+336 x^3+2016 x^2+2304 x+256}{x^4+144 x^3+2016 x^2+5376 x+2304}$$ which is much better.

For the same number of coefficients, Padé approximants are incredibly more powerful than Taylor expansions. For example, in the case you gave, over the range $3\leq x \leq 5$, the largest error is less than $2.5 \times 10^{-9}$ that is to say more than ten times smaller than the result of a Taylor expansion to $O\left((x-4)^8\right)$.

We could play a lot with this kind of work and be sure that it is used a lot for many problems.

**Edit** *(four years later)*

Concerning the first part of the problem, we can make it more general and write (keeping the idea of a $[4,4]$ Padé approximant built at $x=a$)
$$\sqrt[n] x=\sqrt[n] a\frac{1+b_1 t+b_2t^2+b_3t^3+b_4t^4}{1+c_1 t+c_2t^2+c_3t^3+c_4t^4} \quad \text{where} \quad t=\frac{x-a}{2 a n}$$
where the coefficients are
$$b_1=4n+1$$ $$ b_2=\frac{3(3 n+1) (4 n+1)}{7}$$ $$b_3=\frac{2(2 n+1) (3 n+1) (4 n+1)}{21}$$ $$ b_4=\frac{(n+1) (2 n+1) (3 n+1) (4 n+1)}{105}  $$
$$c_1=4n-1$$ $$ c_2=\frac{3(3 n-1) (4 n-1)}{7}$$ $$c_3=\frac{2(2 n-1) (3 n-1) (4 n-1)}{21}$$ $$ c_4=\frac{(n-1) (2 n-1) (3 n-1) (4 n-1)}{105}  $$

Comment: That is very interesting. Now I wonder why taking binomial expansions of powers of small Pisot-Vijayaraghavan numbers gives a Pade approximant... Seems quite fascinating to me.

Comment: (any analytic function, otherwise the result can be weird)

Comment: Very good explanation. +1 for the same.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the OP started with the observation that, when $(3+\sqrt8)^8$ is expanded into an expression of the form $a+b\sqrt8$, then $\sqrt8\approx a/b$, and similarly for other square roots.  There is a fairly simple explanation for all this, based on examining the *conjugate* expression(s), $(3-\sqrt8)^8=(0.1715729\ldots)^8\approx0.00000075$.

If $(3+\sqrt8)^8=a+b\sqrt8$, then $(3-\sqrt8)^8=a-b\sqrt8$, hence $(3+\sqrt8)^8+(3-\sqrt8)^8=2a$.  But since $3-\sqrt8=0.1715729\ldots$ is less than $1$, its eight power is *much* less than $1$, and so we have

$$2a=(3+\sqrt8)^8+(3-\sqrt8)^8\approx(3+\sqrt8)^8=a+b\sqrt8$$

from which $\sqrt8\approx a/b$ follows.

Comment: Thank you for that very simple and useful explanation. That explains perfectly why we can extract a good approximation for $\sqrt{n}$ from such powers, and also explains why the resulting formula is a ratio of binomial terms. Combined with Peter's insight about the role of the formula for $m$, I guess that pretty much explains everything I was wondering about. The only thing left to ask I guess is exactly why we get the Pade approximant.

Comment: This answer is much closer to the intent of the question, so I clearly prefer it to the answers above. It is an open question whether the resulting fraction actually is a Pade-approximant, I have doubts whether this is the case.

Comment: @Barry Cipra This answer of yours was the crucial step in helping me to understand why the formula was so accurate, even for noninteger $n$. I've written up my own answer just now putting everything together, but it's basically just extending the method of this answer of yours to all $m$ and $n$. This answer deserves another upvote!

Answer (score 1):

This is related to [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) $x^2-ny^2=1$, which is to be solved over the integers with $n$ as a parameter.  For any non-square $n$ there is a infinite series of solutions.  Given one or two solutions, another may be generated by the [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity). If you have two solutions $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, another solution will be $(ac+nbd, ad+bc)$, which you can verify by doing the algebra.   For $n=2$ the base solution is $(3,2)$, which is followed by $(17,12), (577, 408)$ and so on.  This given $\frac 32=1.5, \frac {17}{12}\approx 1.416666, \frac{577}{408} \approx 1.414216$ and so on as approximations to $\sqrt 2$

Comment: This is interesting, but some more explanation specifically relating to the formulae I mentioned would be useful.